PIR sensor and the fault detection related to it
Well I am Working on a PIR occupancy sensor project and the issue is, it is having false detection on occasions like when an air conditioner or a fan is turned on, well I can't figure what to do?

Does the false detection also happen if the sensor is made blind, e.g. inside an enclosure? If yes, there is an EMI problem.

As there is no physical difference between the heat from a human body and the heat from the heating system (they both emit electromagnetic waves at the same wavelength), PIR sensors cannot distinguish the two. There is one difference, though: a human moves about the room. Therefore, what you need to do is prevent the heat from the heating system from moving around the room. Or, better yet, switch to a different motion detector, such as ultrasound or microwave.

The problem is that the sensor is creating noise every time when a ceiling fan or AC is turned on. And it is very difficult to differentiate between the signal caused by human detection and the signal caused by these external factors.
